# Plot the general and a particular solution for this differential equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In a previous question, I had obtained a differential equation from:

Starts with this **implicit equation**:

`(x - a)^2 + y^2 == 1`(1) ( circles on x -axis ) $(x-a)^2+y^2=1$

Is the set of equations of the given circles. This set contains one parameter namely `a`. So, it is the solution set of a differential equation of the first order.

**NOTE**: see [`my previous question`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267531/how-implicit-differentiate-in-order-to-get-a-differential-equation) for additional details how the **differential equation** is derived

This differential equation :
`DSolve[y[x]^2*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 1 - y[x]^2,  {y[x]}, {x}]`

Is a general solution : how to plot the general solution and a particular solution for say in the origin (0,0) ? (type ODE ?: first order))

**EDIT**
The integralcurves

[image]

Comment: The general solution is a family of solutions. How do you want to plot these? Only particular solutions can be plotted.

Comment: (x - a)^2 + y^2 == 1 is a implicit equation, and for some values of parameter a i can plot these circles
Now it is a ODE with parameter C to plot,

Answer (score 3):

Draw the slope field for the general solution. There are two solutions. Pick one

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode = y[x]^2*y'[x]^2 == 1 - y[x]^2;
sol = Solve[ode, y'[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets try the second one

```
fld = VectorPlot[{1, Sqrt[1 - y^2]/y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add a particular solution by specifying a solution curve that passes through a point. Try `{1,1}`

```
fld = VectorPlot[{1, Sqrt[1 - y^2]/y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> Gray, 
  StreamPoints -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can try different particular solutions by changing the stream point location. See help for many more options.

Picking a point that the solution curve passes through is like picking a value for your `a` parameter. You are basically saying you want to look at some particular solution curve.

See [drawing-lines-on-differential-equation-slope-field](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214785/drawing-lines-on-differential-equation-slope-field) for more examples.

Comment: Nasser, thanks. you use y', while i have used y.
Its a family of circles with centre on x-axis.
The other y' gives another part of the circle

Comment: @janhardo I am using VectorPlot which uses the form $y'=f(x,y)$ to plot the solution curves. It has nothing to do with your implicit solution.

Comment: Another idea is to use the general solutions with C : a example : `Table[y[t] /. %[[1]] /. C[1] -> n, {n, -500, 500, 50}]`

Comment: Nasser: quote  "It has nothing to do with your implicit solution."  ?
I ended up with a differential equation..

Comment: @janhardo Yes, you can always do it manually like this. But the whole point is that VectorField will plot the solution curves for you without having to solve the ODE at all. You can not just plot the general solution as it has unknowns. VectorField shows family of solution curves. You use `StreamPoints` to basically highlight one of these solution curves, which correspond to one particular solution curve.

Comment: Nasser, yes with a VectorField, but it are a family of circles as general solution , and i do see here a circle in the origin with radius 1 also too.

Also two singular solutions at y=1 and y= -1

Comment: Its seems to be a complicate thing to use VectorPlot to the show in the whole complete family of circles , plus two sigular lines

Answer (score 3):

Manipulate parameters to get overview

```
eq = (x - a)^2 + y^2 == 1;

deq = D[eq /. y -> y[x], x]

eq /. y -> y[x] /. x -> a

(*   y[a]^2 == 1   *)

ysol[a_] = y /. DSolve[{deq, y[a]^2 == 1}, y, x]

(*   {Function[{x}, -Sqrt[1 - a^2 + 2 a x - x^2]], 
      Function[{x}, Sqrt[1 - a^2 + 2 a x - x^2]]}   *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Through[ysol[a][x]]], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> 3, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, -2}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Akku14,thanks for this dynamic plot. I added a picture at the question, and it are all circles. In your example it is a circle with center (-2,0) and radius 1 for a circle 
It looks a ellipse now ;)

Comment: Add `AspectRatio -> 1 ` to Plot to get equal scaling for x and y achses. Changed it now.

Comment: It is an ingenious plot you have made and so again adapted by you, nicely done
I'm not doing it after you :).
Challencing too is to plot these integralcurves ( circles)  in a directionfield ( don't know how to do this yet )